# Cesar Cipher on Python beginner level

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
''' Cesar Cipher '''
def encrypt(word, shift):

    word = word.lower()

    for i in word:
        r = chr(ord(i)+shift)
        if r > "z":
            r = chr(ord(i) - 26 + shift)
        word = word.replace(i, r)

    return word

if __name__ == "__main__": print encrypt("programming", 3)
```

This gives me wrong answers on shifts higher than 1 and words longer then 2. I can't figure out why. Any help please?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Answer (score 4):

Thilo explains the problem exactly. Let's step through it:

```
''' Cesar Cipher '''
def encrypt(word, shift):

    word = word.lower()

    for i in word:
        r = chr(ord(i)+shift)
        if r > "z":
            r = chr(ord(i) - 26 + shift)
        word = word.replace(i, r)

    return word
```

Try `encrypt('abc', 1)` and see what happens:

```
First loop:
    i = 'a'
    r = chr(ord('a')+1) = 'b'
    word = 'abc'.replace('a', 'b') = 'bbc'
Second loop:
    i = 'b'
    r = chr(ord('b')+1) = 'c'
    word = 'bbc'.replace('b', 'c') = 'ccc'
Third loop:
    i = 'c'
    r = chr(ord('c')+1) = 'd'
    word = 'ccc'.replace('c', 'd') = 'ddd'
```

You don't want to replace *every* instance of `i` with `r`, just this one. How would you do this? Well, if you keep track of the index, you can just replace at that index. The built-in `enumerate` function lets you get each index and each corresponding value at the same time.

```
for index, ch in enumerate(word):
    r = chr(ord(ch)+shift)
    if r > "z":
        r = chr(ord(ch) - 26 + shift)
    word = new_word_replacing_one_char(index, r)
```

Now you just have to write that `new_word_replacing_one_char` function, which is pretty easy if you know slicing. (If you haven't learned slicing yet, you may want to convert the string into a `list` of characters, so you can just say `word[index] = r`, and then convert back into a string at the end.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Python likes replacing characters in the word while you are iterating over it, but one thing that seems to be a problem for sure is repeated letters, because `replace` will replace *all* occurrences of the letter, not just the one you are currently looking at, so you will end up shifting those repeated letters more than once (as you hit them again in a later iteration).

Come to think of it, this will also happen with non-repeated letters. For example, shifting ABC by 1 will become -> BBC -> CCC -> DDD in your three iterations.

Comment: Replacing characters while iterating over it isn't a problem, because `replace` makes a whole new string, leaving the old one that you're iterating over untouched. But your second paragraph is probably exactly what the OP is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this assignment as well.  The hint is you have to keep track of where the values wrap, and use that to your advantage.  I also recommend using the `upper` function call so everything is the same case, reduces the number of checks to do.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are immutable - that is they cannot be changed. Lists, however, can be. So to use your algorithm, use a list instead:

```
''' Cesar Cipher '''
def encrypt(word, shift):

    word = word.lower()
    # Convert the word to a list
    word = list(word)

    # Iterate over the word by index
    for i in xrange(len(word)):
        # Get the character at i
        c = word[i]
        # Apply shift algorithm
        r = chr(ord(c)+shift)
        if r > "z":
            r = chr(ord(c) - 26 + shift)
        # Replace the character at i
        word[i] = r

    # Convert the list back to a string
    return ''.join(word)

if __name__ == "__main__": print encrypt("programming", 3)
```